# Have you heard of using 2 different disc to bring computer back from the dead?

Tags: windows-xp

So virus got XP laptop. I had to use the XP disc not for it to get to the repair section to format. Then back to the Disc meant for it to put Windows in. That as went up to partially loading windows but locked up there. I then backed it up and came back but it jumped over the part where you put your administrator name and all that in there. But it came back to play my game again.

Comment: That was how XP installs worked for some computers.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Okay the computer has gone down. So you use two different Window XP's to put XP back in the computer. As each disc is meant for another computer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague and XP is very notably insecure and so prone to being hacked and ruined.

Here is a very good article on (a) repairing XP and (b) why it uses two CDs.

[XP Repairs](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-reinstall-or-repair-windows-xp/)

> For some branded computers such as HP, there are usually 2 CDs. One is
> the Recovery CD and the other is the Operating System CD. To repair
> Windows, you need to boot up the Operating System CD first, then it
> will ask you to put in the Recovery CD for verification. Once you’ve
> loaded the Recovery CD and verified, you will need to put back the
> Operating System CD. Now it will start the Windows XP repair process
> Read More:
> https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-reinstall-or-repair-windows-xp/

Comment: Yeh I know you can get a repair disc as for it but this was as 2 discs that was for different computers.

Comment: You need the CDs for each computer if the 2 are a different version.